# Use alias name as a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using this query to to calculate yearly finance values.

```
select [Year],
       [FinanceValue-2014],
       [FinanceValue-2013],
       [FinanceValue-2012],
       [FinanceValue-2014]-[FinanceValue-2013] as [FinanceValue Variance]
```

Now I need to multiply the [FinanceValue Variance] * 2.50 and for that how can I use the alias name as column in the query. I tried this but doesn't work.

```
 select [Year],
        [FinanceValue-2014],
        [FinanceValue-2013],
        [FinanceValue-2012],
        [FinanceValue-2014]-[FinanceValue-2013] as [FinanceValue Variance],
        [FinanceValue Variance] * 2.50    as [NewVariance] 
from Finance
```

SumofVariance output will be like 5690.5893656 Also how can I show the SumofVariance to round off 4 decimal places like this 5690.5894. Really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using table expressions as below. In any clause of the outer query, you can refer to column aliases that were assigned in the SELECT clause of the inner query. This helps you get around the fact that you can’t refer to column aliases assigned in the SELECT clause in query clauses that are logically processed prior to the SELECT clause (for example, WHERE or GROUP BY).

So Write as:

```
select [Year],
       [FinanceValue-2014],
       [FinanceValue-2013],
       [FinanceValue-2012],
       [FinanceValue Variance],
       Round([FinanceValue Variance] * 2.50,4) as [NewVariance]
from (
select [Year],
       [FinanceValue-2014],
       [FinanceValue-2013],
       [FinanceValue-2012],
       [FinanceValue-2014]-[FinanceValue-2013] as [FinanceValue Variance]      
from Finance)T
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CROSS APPLY to create aliases

```
SELECT [Year],
       [FinanceValue-2014],
       [FinanceValue-2013],
       [FinanceValue-2012],
       [FinanceValue Variance],
       [FinanceValue Variance] * 2.50    as [NewVariance] 
FROM Finance
     CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT [FinanceValue-2014]-[FinanceValue-2013] as [FinanceValue Variance]
     ) AS CA1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use the alias name when doing additional calculations. You'll have do the full calculation and then alias that instead.